# My country's domain registrar only supports nameserver, but Squarespace only supports Cname and A Records

Tags: dns, hosting, cname, nameservers

I have built a site on squarespace, and ready to launch, so I purchased a domain from my country's domain registrar (in Cyprus all .com.cy domains are managed by the local University). However they are asking me what Squarespace's nameservers are, but according to this article: https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206541857-My-domain-provider-is-asking-me-to-use-Squarespace-s-nameservers

Squarespace does not allow this. Is there anyway to get around this issue? Perhaps some sort of middle man that will receive requests to its nameserver and then forward to squarespace via CName and A Records?

Sorry if my terminology is all wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

In somewhat laymen's terms:

You need to distinguish between 3 different (yet related) services:

1. Domain name registration - you pay for your domain name here (in your case, it is country's domain registrar). Except for the name itself, here you need to enter your Domain Name server names, which will point to where the next service is hosted:
2. DNS service - here is where you enter all your records (A, MX, CNAME, ...) which point to your other services (web hosting, mail servers, etc..)
3. Service hosting provider (for example web hosting or email service, in your case it is Squarespace)

You can have different parties host these services for you, but it is not uncommon that one service provider can offer two or all three of these services.

So, you are correct, you need middle man :) ([DNS service provider/hosting](https://www.google.nl/search?q=dns%20hosting)). You should be able to find good one for free or very cheap (less than 1EUR/month). Once you get one, they will give you DNS server names which you will enter at your country registrar, and also they will provide some way (usually web interface) to enter your CNAME and A records (which were provided by Squarespace)