# Delegate Nic(.ar) domain name to vps or domain host

Tags: dns, nameservers, mx-record, reverse-dns, a-records

I've bought a .com.ar domain from nic.ar, just to claim a domain before starting the publicity campaign of a project.

I was trying to setup a MX record to forward emails from the domain to a google account, when realized there's no dns record management panel in nic.ar, as it isn't a domain host. I can instead delegate the domain to a nameserver, and specify an ipv4 and ipv6.

I can't get to understand what I've to do next. I've my own VPS, should I delegate the domain to the VPS, using my hosting service's nameservers? If so, how should I manage the dns records from the host? I'm used to work with nginx to handle server's traffic, but once the request reaches the server it has already resolved all the domains involved. Is there something like a 'domain proxy'?

Can I somehow evade manual configuration of the domain host by 'masking' this domain to another domain properly hosted in websites like hostinger, freenom, namecheap, etc?

Sorry if I'm messing things up, the whole concept of a domain host being separated from the actual domain name did totally lost me.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58129545/1145196

Answer (score 0):

To anyone facing the same issue, I got it to work using [cloudns.net](https://www.cloudns.net).

As I understood it, a domain name points (delegates) to a domain hosting service's nameservers. Once the delegation is setup, you should tell the domain host that you want to setup registers for your domain name, so when traffic from your domain arrives, it will know what to answer.

Sites like [donweb](https://donweb.com), [hostinger](https://www.hostinger.com/) and [freenom](https://www.freenom.com) hide all this by buying a domain name and configuring it to point to their own nameservers automagically in the background.

Regarding my question about using these 'all in one' services as host, it's *sometimes* possible, depending on your [TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain). It seems like .ar doesn't support this, so it isn't possible to use any of these services to host a .ar

Answer (score 0):

I have many domains registered through [donweb](https://donweb.com/es-ar/registro-de-dominios) (because it also allows me to pay in Argentine pesos) and, although by default they place their NS, you can change them whenever you want from your customer panel. It is even possible to do it with .COM.AR and .AR domains

When you register a domain with them, they also provide you with a DNS zone and you can add, remove and modify the records. In that case you don't need a separate DNS service.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31013058)

Comment: Hey Diego, thank you for your answer!
Sadly, it's not related to the original question. Registrar services such as nic.ar don't have any NS. These are provided by DNS hosting services, wich nic.ar is not

Comment: I was not saying that NIC.AR provided NS services. I was just saying that in Donweb, despite the fact that by default they place their NS in the domains, you can easily change them later. Also, if you register your domains with them, you do not need to hire a web hosting service because the DNS service is included.
All the providers you mentioned work in the same way and it is possible to host an .ar domain with any of them.
Finally, if you don't want to register a domain with them or contract a web hosting service with them, you can use free NS services through Cloudflare.